# How do I create a simple multigraph in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use the package tikz to create a simple multigraph that should look like this (done in MS Paint):

[image: A very bad picture]

I wrote a code using the package tikz to make something very similar. Here it is:

[image: Using tikz]

However, I don't know how to make it clear that the node 3 is connected to itself. Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  [scale=1,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]

  \node (n1) at (5,7) {1};

  \node (n2) at (3,5)  {2};

  \node (n3) at (5,5)  {3};

  \node (n4) at (7,5) {4};

  \node (n5) at (5,3)  {5};

  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n3,n2/n3,n4/n3,n5/n3}

    \draw (\from) -- (\to);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: you may wanna have a look at this: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/state-machine/
using the `[loop above]` option of edges, should do the trick. btw note that he is using the `automata` library

Comment: @Rico This is a directed graph, I don't understand how I can use this to make an undirected multigraph. Thanks though for showing me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the `topaths` library (which is loaded by the default) provides us with a few `loop` styles there is no `loop above right` but we can define one.

If we set `every loop` (which contains `->, shorten >=1pt`) to an empty style we also remove the arrow tip and the shorten amount.

I also took the liberty to use the `positioning` library for the positioning of the nodes and the `edge` operator to connect the nodes.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  loop above right/.style={above right, out= 60, in= 30, loop},
  loop above left/.style ={above left,  out=150, in=120, loop},
  loop below right/.style={below right, out=330, in=300, loop},
  loop below left/.style ={below left,  out=240, in=210, loop}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  auto=left,
  every node/.style={circle, fill=blue!20, outer sep=+0pt},
  every loop/.style=,
  node distance=1cm]

  \node              (n1) {1};
  \node[below=of n1] (n3) {3};
  \node[below=of n3] (n5) {5};
  \node[ left=of n3] (n2) {2};
  \node[right=of n3] (n4) {4};

  \path[thick] (n3) edge (n1)
                    edge (n2)
                    edge (n4)
                    edge (n5)
                    edge[loop above right] ();
  \path[red] (n1) edge [loop left]  ()
             (n5) edge [loop right] ()
             (n2) edge [loop below] ()
             (n4) edge [loop above] ()
             (n3) edge [loop above left]  ()
                  edge [loop below left]  ()
                  edge [loop below right] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]